# How to store complete path using 7z on linux

Tags: linux, command-line, path, 7-zip

I am looking for a simple way to backup files that have changed in the last 24 hours and creating a daily 7zip file ( I don't need permssion or users just files ).

Using the following command I can pass a list of changed file to 7Zip, and this works well. However no path information of the changed files is stored in 7zip.

```
/usr/bin/find /local-storage/public_html/ -type f -size -25M -mtime -1 -print | /usr/bin/xargs -n 1 /usr/bin/7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 /local-storage/public_html_2013-09-03.7z
```

So if I now try to extract that 7zip file it is all just in 1 directory and no paths.

Hoping someone here can point out what I have missed :-)

Comment: What command are you using to extract?

Comment: 7z x public_html_2013-09-03.7z

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that `7z` can do that, that seems to be what they mean in this section of the man page:

```
   On Linux/Unix, in order  to  backup  directories  you
   must use tar :
    -  to backup a directory  : tar cf - directory | 7za a -si directory.tar.7z
    -  to  restore  your  backup  :  7za  x  -so  directory.tar.7z | tar xf -
```

Instead, I would suggest creating an uncompressed tar ball and *then* compressing it with 7z:

```
find /local-storage/public_html/ -type f  -mtime -1 -print0 | 
xargs --null tar rf foo.tar && 
7za a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 /local-storage/public_html_2013-09-03.tar.7z foo.tar &&
rm foo.tar
```

This will create a file called `public_html_2013-09-03.tar.7z` which will contain the tar ball `foo.tar`. You can then extract everything and keep the right paths (directories will be created if not present and files will be overwritten so make sure you know what you're doing):

```
7z x -so foo.tar.7z | tar rf -
```

Comment: That `tar cf` should be a `tar rf` in case `xargs` needs to make more than one `tar` call. But really, if you're going to be creating a tarball as the end result, you may as well just use `xz` for compression.

Comment: @jjlin good point, answer edited. As for the compression I agree completely, using `7z` is not worth the trouble but perhaps the OP just _needs_ the highest compression available for some reason.

Comment: Is this a Linux-specific limitation? 7Zip in Windows stores my full path, which can be used by extracting with the `x` command instead of the `e` command.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `7z` isn't particularly well-suited to what you're trying to do. Nevertheless, if you're set on using `7z`, you can still do what you need by creating a temporary tree of files and creating the archive from that. For example, you could put this list of commands into a shell script:

```
cd /tmp
find /local-storage/public_html -type f -size -25M -mtime -1 -print0 | xargs -0 tar -rf public_html_2013-09-03.tar
tar -xf public_html_2013-09-03.tar
7z a -r -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 /local-storage/public_html_2013-09-03.7z local-storage
rm -rf local-storage public_html_2013-09-03.tar
```

That's the basic idea. Note the `-r` passed to `7z`. You can enhance this with better temp directory handling, generating a date string automatically, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your input. I found a method that whilst not great works for me in my situation. I have used some ideas from posters here and created the following bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
TIMESINCELINUXSTART="$(date +%s)"
YESTERDAY=`date -d "1 days ago" '+%Y-%m-%d'`
cd /local-storage/public_html/
/usr/bin/find . -type f -size -25M -mtime -1 > /tmp/"$TIMESINCELINUXSTART"-changed-files.txt
/bin/mkdir -p /tmp/"$TIMESINCELINUXSTART"/public_html
/usr/bin/rsync --files-from=/tmp/"$TIMESINCELINUXSTART"-changed-files.txt /local-storage/public_html /tmp/"$TIMESINCELINUXSTART"/public_html/
/usr/bin/7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 /local-storage/snapshots/public_html-changes-during-"$YESTERDAY".7z /tmp/"$TIMESINCELINUXSTART"/public_html
/bin/rm /tmp/"$TIMESINCELINUXSTART"-changed-files.txt
/bin/rm -rf /tmp/"$TIMESINCELINUXSTART"
```

If anyone has improvements or comments on this, you are invited to comment. The only addition I would like to add it to not create an 7zip file if no changed files are found.